# Change settings of BracketHighlighter Package Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, settings, sublimetext, package-control

how can i change the threshold in my BracketHighlighter to highlight brackets that are farther apart?
Instead of displaying a question mark in the left bar I still want to be able to locate the brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the settings either in

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/BracketHighlighter/bh_core.sublime-settings
```

or in your user settings

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/bh_core.sublime-settings
```

Relevant settings include:

```
// Match brackets only when the cursor is touching the inside of the bracket
"match_only_adjacent": false,

// Character threshold to search
"search_threshold": 55000,

// Set mode for string escapes to ignore (regex|string)
"bracket_string_escape_mode": "string",

// Set max number of multi-select brackets that will be searched automatically
"auto_selection_threshold" : 10000,
```

Comment: thanks! Didn't know where to find the settings file.

Answer (score 2):

While in Sublime navigate to preferences then goto package settings and select bracket - user settings. Insert the following lines to increase threshold or ignore (not recommended). The default is 5K.

```
// Character threshold to search
"search_threshold": 1005000,

// Ignore threshold
"ignore_threshold": false,
```